# Centering an image through a div

Tags: html, css

I am needing to center my image using css. I am having troubles, and cannot find out how to do it.

HTML

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<title>
AG.
</title>

<body>

<img src="images/logo.png" alt="AG" class="logo">


</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.logo {
width: 500px;
height: 467px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Add display:block to .logo class - if you just need horizontal centering....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't center an inline element that way - you need to give it a `display: block` style:

```css
.logo {
  width: 500px;
  height: 467px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/500/467" alt="AG" class="logo">
```

Answer (score 0):

First put your image inside a container, otherwise the height and width are just editing the size of the picture.

I added it into a div and then added the properties into its own container.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uHaGC

Here is a code pen.

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>

<title>
AG.
</title>

<body>
<div id="logo">
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="AG">
  </div>

</body>

</html>


#logo {
  position: relative;
width: 50%;

margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

The #logo tag centers it (maybe not depending on your resolution). Just set a new tag for your image and change the size!

I prefer using percentages rather than amount of pixels because it then looks better on bigger or smaller resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

To wrap the image into a div,

change the html and add an ID like so: (By the way, I used a google image as a place holder, but you get the idea)

```
<div id="pic">
     <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2014/jonas-salks-100th-birthday-5130655667060736-hp.jpg" alt="AG" class="logo">
</div>
```

and then for the CSS

```
#pic {
width: 500px;
height: 467px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

See it work at http://jsfiddle.net/e5pdof91/

}